# classification of boundary values of one complex variable holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, boundary-value-problem

I know there are infinitely many one complex variable holomorphic functions in the unit disk that can be taken null at the boundary. But, is there a way to distinguish them ? for example, could we say that they are classified by a germ of function i.e. all the normal derivatives of a function null in the unit circle ?

Comment: what do you mean by "taken null at the boundary"? If a function is analytic on the open unit disc, continuous on its closure and zero on the boundary, then it is identically zero.

Comment: @wisefool no I mean of course continuous on the open unit disk and that converges to the null function in the boundary

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "converges"? What kind of boundary value are you considering?

Comment: @wisefool, I mean simple convergence (non necessarily uniform)

Comment: So if $f(z)=\sum_n a_nz^n$ you ask that *for every* $z_0$ with $|z_0|=1$ you have that $\sum_n a_nz_0^n=0$? Then by Abel's limit theorem, you have that $\lim_{t\to 1^{-}} f(tz_0)=\sum_{n}a_n z_0^n=0$ for *every* $z_0$ with $|z_0|=1$, but then for the Lusin-Privalov theorem, $f$ has to be a constant on the disc (it is enough that the set of such $z_0$ is metrically dense and of second Baire category in some arc of the unit circle).